# How to do Correlation for below scenario

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

I need the value beside "selected" in below for correlation
Code:

```
id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GVMembers_ctl04_ddlRelation" class="ddl" style="width:100px;">
<option selected="selected" value="6">Husband</option>
<option value="1">Wife</option>
<option value="2">Father</option>
<option value="3">Brother</option>
<option value="4">Sister</option>
<option value="5">Daughter</option>
<option value="7">Spouse</option>
<option value="8">Son</option>
<option value="9">Mother</option>
<option value="10">Mother In Law</option>
<option value="11">Brother In Law</option>
<option value="12">Father In Law</option>
<option value="13">Others</option>
```

but cannot use regex because client is using LR9.1
also when save param is to capture "" 
the ord is changing for every vuser.
Please help me with this.
And also the Selected values will also me changing from 1 to 13.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<option selected="selected"` as LeftBounddary and `</option>` as Right Boundary,which will fetch `value="6">Husband` 
And to get the value(i.e Husband) you have to do some string manipulation 
Eg:- strtok function using > as delimiter

Comment: Thank you, i was able to solve the issue using string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
web_reg_save_param_regexp(
    "ParamName=SelectedOption",
    "RegExp=selected\" value=\"\\d+\">(.*?)<\/option>",
    LAST);
```

That will only grab the 'husband' part, if you want the option number you can use:

```
web_reg_save_param_regexp(
    "ParamName=SelectedOption",
    "RegExp=selected\" value=\"(\\d+)\">.*?<\/option>",
    LAST);
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the responding, The bove Reg Ex is working fine but i cannot use it as the 9.10 controller does not support Reg Ex.